# Linking with boost libraries fails

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu, linker, autotools

I am trying to compile this app: http://code.google.com/p/pantera-tagger/

"configure" script succeeded, all neccessary libraries (boost, openmpi, icu etc.) are installed through Synaptic (on Ubuntu 11.10 amd64). I type "make", compilation also seems to succeed, but linking fails as follows:

```
libtool: link: /usr/bin/mpicxx -I/usr/include -I../third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/Corpus -DSEGMENT_PATH=\"/usr/local/libexec/pantera-tagger:/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/third_party/segment\" -DENGINES_PATH=\"/usr/local/share/pantera-tagger/engines:/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/engines\" -g -O2 -pthread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/bin/Corpus -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib/pantera-tagger -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/third_party/morfeusz/lib -o .libs/wrapper_test wrapper_test.o ../third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/bin/Corpus/libcorpus.so  -L/usr/lib -lboost_serialization -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -lboost_mpi -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -ldl -lm -lmorfeusz -L../third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/bin/Corpus -lcorpus ./.libs/libpantera.so nlpcommon/.libs/libnlpcommon.so -ltcmalloc -pthread
libtool: link: /usr/bin/mpicxx -I/usr/include -I../third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/Corpus -DSEGMENT_PATH=\"/usr/local/libexec/pantera-tagger:/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/third_party/segment\" -DENGINES_PATH=\"/usr/local/share/pantera-tagger/engines:/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/engines\" -g -O2 -pthread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/bin/Corpus -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib/pantera-tagger -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/mlenart/src/pantera-tagger2/third_party/morfeusz/lib -o .libs/pantera_eval eval.o ../third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/bin/Corpus/libcorpus.so  -L/usr/lib -lboost_serialization -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -lboost_mpi -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -ldl -lm -lmorfeusz -L../third_party/TaKIPI18/Linux/bin/Corpus -lcorpus ./.libs/libpantera.so nlpcommon/.libs/libnlpcommon.so -ltcmalloc -pthread
./.libs/libpantera.so: undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::~basic_text_iprimitive()'
./.libs/libpantera.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::is_combining_implementation(unsigned short)'
./.libs/libpantera.so: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::archive::archive_exception'
./.libs/libpantera.so: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<wchar_t, boost::regex_traits<wchar_t, boost::cpp_regex_traits<wchar_t> > >::do_assign(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, unsigned int)'
### .... and much more of it ....
```

I had older version of boost in /usr/local but removed it (needed newer version) and had to recompile "pantera-tagger" application. Now it fails with any version of boost. What may cause the problem?

Comment: Might want to try [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)